# Where's XmlHttpRequest defined in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm trying to write an IE BHO (ported from Chrome) where I need to use XSS with jQuery. I am hoping that I can enable XSS for my own addon/JavaScript by replacing the jQuery function, $.ajaxSettings.xhr with,

```
$.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() { return window.myExtension.Xhr() }
```

Where myExtension.Xhr is a COM function defined in my extension (and myExtension is added via `((IExpando)window).addProperty)`.

I tried defining my Xhr() function as (C# implementing COM),

```
public object Xhr()
{
    return new MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest();
}
```

But this fails when jQuery tries to set the onload property of the XHR (at jquery-2.1.3.js:8617). So it looks like I'm using the wrong COM XmlHttpRequest (MSXML2.XMLHttp also has a missing onload). **So where is the "real" XmlHttpRequest defined**?

```
// Listen to events
xhr.onload = callback();
xhr.onerror = callback("error");

// Create the abort callback
callback = xhrCallbacks[ id ] = callback("abort");
```

I can of course just use one of the several methods of submitting GET/POST requests in .NET, but then I'd have to dirty my code with workarounds for IE when doing XSS ajax calls (since Firefox and Chrome extensions can do XSS with appropriate permissions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a real solution to my question, but a sort of workaround for what I ultimately want to do is to use jQuery 1.x instead, which is able to (and does, for IE6-8) work with the old MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest.

I am posting this for anyone would like to run cross-domain Ajax requests in scripts they inject via a BHO.

First, define this interface:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IExtension
{
    [DispId(1)]
    object Xhr();

    [DispId(2)]
    string OptionalFooBar();
}
```

And implement it somewhere, e.g. in this case my BHO itself:

```
    //Exposed to JS
    public object Xhr()
    {
        return new MSXML2.XMLHTTP();
    }
```

And once your document completes, say in an OnDocumentComplete handler, add a property to the window through IDispatchEx to expose your methods:

```
    void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        dynamic window = null;
        IExpando windowEx = null;
        try
        {
            if (pDisp != this.site)
                return;

            var document2 = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
            var document3 = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument3;

            window = document2.parentWindow;
            windowEx = window as IExpando;
            windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension")
            window.myExtension = this;
      }
```

And then in your JS, after jQuery has been loaded:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () { return window.myExtension.Xhr(); }
```